# Why do raindrops look like sticks?

Tags: visible-light, air

I always thought that raindrops look like this emoji .
But today, I shot it in slow-mo (see on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/a2gstm3L-4s)), and they look more like sticks.

Was it some light effect of my camera, or do they really look like that? And if it's the real deal, why do they look like that?

---

**Edit:** I found another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3W5BwkPrtgg) that I took from that rain. I didn't see it at first, but after looking again, it shows rain drops as little balls.

I took the videos 10 min apart. The second video(with balls) is when the rain just started.

Why does the rain look like sticks in one video and like balls in another? I used the same camera to record it.

[image]
*Screenshot at [00:00:18](https://youtu.be/3W5BwkPrtgg?t=10)*

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24944469

Comment: This might be a better question for the Photography SE.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G6omXLTAj0

Comment: see this video of raindrops falling, they are streaks,, exxcept the ones slow enough while bouncing off the leaves , where they are white dots https://www.videvo.net/video/close-up-shot-rain-drops-falling-on-leaves/783004/

Comment: Clickable link to the URL for the OP's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2gstm3L-4s

Comment: Same reason bugs look like rods.

Comment: See this video for an explanation of how to shoot good videos of rain https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2picMQC-9E

Comment: Was the earlier video taken with slow motion? I can't see enough movement in it io tell. There might be something about the way your camera does slow motion that makes the difference.

Comment: Ultimately, it's just motion blur. When you look up, you get shorter streaks, especially higher in the frame. On top of that, who knows what the software in your camera is doing - it might be auto-adjusting various camera settings, and it might be interpolating the frames to make the video appear to have a higher framerate than it actually does. So the filming conditions may be different, even though it's the same camera.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Small raindrops are roughly spherical. As they get larger, they flatten (see figure).

[image]

Even larger raindrops are unstable, and break up:

[image]

(figures from https://gpm.nasa.gov/education/articles/shape-of-a-raindrop).

For spherical rain drops, Mie theory is used for computing a radar cross section (measured in dBZ, which is a log-10 scale of $10\times\ {\rm mm^6/m^3}$, one of the strangest units in science, IMHO). The larger drops' asymmetric shape can be retrieved by comparing horizontal and vertical radar cross sections.

Comment: I doubt that this exact case is related to large raindrop size, because in video it is seen like vertical sticks, while when large raindrop is about to divide - it becomes like a "hantel",- i.e. horizontal stick. So OP's noticed phenomena can't be related to overgrowing raindrops.

Comment: Way back when I was an undergrad, and this book (https://books.google.com/books/about/Bubbles_Drops_and_Particles.html?id=R0AnnQEACAAJ) was in its first edition (late 70s), I took a "Particulate Systems" class from one of the authors (Grace).  It definitely included high speed photos of falling water droplets looking either spherical, hamburger bun shaped or nearly red-blood-cell shape depending on their size (just like the nasa.gov illustration)

Comment: Why is the reflectivity of spherical rain droplets proportional to the sixth power of their diameter anyway? It seems that fact explains the mm^6 unit, but I can't find any references online as to where that relationship comes from.

Comment: @jogloran https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering#Small_size_parameter_approximation

Comment: @JEB I updated the question, please review

Comment: @Flydog57 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdrometer

Answer (score 56):

Your shutter speed is too slow, and you are seeing the raindrops travel within each video frame. Falling raindrops are approximately spherical. The teardrop shape sometimes occurs in droplets moving across a surface, such as a raindrop on glass (or, I suppose, a teardrop on a person’s face).

Comment: The proof that they are usually highly spherical is the way the rainbow looks. An inclusion of a small non-sphericity leads to [twinned rainbows](https://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/twin1.htm).

Comment: Atmospheric Optics is one of the underappreciated gems of the Internet, and I'm just tickled pink that you linked to it before I did. Excellent point, @Ruslan.

Comment: Ideally, this answer should be supplemented with footage that supports the physical theory with empirical evidence

Comment: @Ruslan, is it possible that tiny water droplets that are not falling are spherical and make rainbows, while falling raindrops usually don't make rainbows and perhaps are twinned when they do?

Comment: To put some numbers on it, a typical raindrop falling at its terminal velocity of 9m/s falls 15cm in one frame of a 60fps video, which seems fairly consistent with the OP's video.

Comment: @JThomas that's unlikely: tiny droplets would result in [fogbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fogbow) instead of rainbow. Besides, twinned rainbow is not a frequent phenomenon, while normal rainbow is, while the rain usually does fall :)

Comment: I agree with Agnishom Chattopadhyay. I would love to see that!

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Frame rate and shutter speed are two different camera settings. The shutter is only open for a fraction of the frame time (often expressed as a fraction of a circle as an angle). A 60fps can have any shutter speed of 1/60s or faster.

Comment: @Ruslan Let me ask the next question -- when you see a rainbow, is it always falling raindrops that make it?

Comment: @JThomas well, it's hard to imagine a scenario where millimeter-scale drops would float in the air, unless they are in the cloud that has high updrafts (in this case we wouldn't see the rainbow because cloud "borders" are made of much smaller drops). So yes, I think we should by default assume that rainbow is produced by falling drops.

Comment: @JThomas You presumably exclude rainbows in droplets from the spray near a waterfall, from a garden hose or sprinkler, from decorative fountains in ponds, or from other non-rain sources of appropriately-sized droplets.

Comment: @rob I just updated the question. The shutter speed alone cannot explain this effect as it's not the case for the second video.

Comment: @IlyaGazman A modern digital camera will dynamically update the shutter speed to account for light conditions. Your second video was probably just taken on a brighter day; note the big patch of blue sky.

Comment: I think the teardrop shape is most commonly seen when observing water (or other liquid) dripping off something such as a tap or windowsill. As the surface tension hangs on to the back of the drop it elongates the drop, which then snaps back into shape quickly, but is momentarily this shape.

Answer (score 11):

Photographic sensor, camera sensor, film... all integrate the light received during the exposure time. The brightness and color of each pixel depends on the sum of all the light received during the exposure. So if an object moves during the exposure, it will look blurred, like this car. The background is stationary, so it is not blurred.

[image]

This is called "motion blur". The amount depends on how far it moves during the exposure. If it doesn't move more than one pixel, then the photo will be very sharp. Playing with the shutter time setting on the camera can give completely different [results](https://www.dpmag.com/how-to/shooting/5-great-waterfall-photography-tips-for-beginners/). On the left, a short exposure time "freezes" the subject. On the left, a long exposure time turns every drop into a long streak, for a more artistic look.

[image]

The video you show was shot with a rather long exposure time, which means the drops are affected by motion blur, and they look like streaks. Here's a picture of water drops shot with a short exposure time:

[image]

Comment: I updated the question. Please review.

Comment: It looks different because the camera will automatically adjust exposure time depending on ambient light conditions, so the picture is exposed correctly. Unless you set everything to manual (if it even has a manual mode).

Answer (score 9):

When I look at individual frames, raindrops look like little white lines about 10 to 20 times as long as they're wide. I think that's how far they fall while one frame is being taken. Maybe some of them are farther away than others, and that makes the length difference.

If you see a series of frames like that, they're going to look like long lines.

I thought while looking at it that some particularly bright ones looked more like sticks than the others, but I didn't find the frames they were in. Maybe they were bright because they were closer, so they were just longer and wider lines.

But I'd consider the possibility that maybe sometimes you get something that isn't an individual raindrop. Imagine you were in a small airplane and you poured a cup of water. Air resistance would quickly spread it out. But maybe some of it would tend to stay together some. You could get some big blobs that followed each other, the leader breaking up the air resistance some for later ones?

So you might see something that wasn't just a random raindrop, but something more, that lasted longer, that your eye might connect?

I can imagine it, but I didn't look long enough to see whether it was there.
[image]

The experimental evidence supports JEBs claims. With a vertical wind tunnel blowing fast enough to keep water droplets stationary, they make the shapes he describes. You can see it for yourself.

[video of falling water droplets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G6omXLTAj0)

So if inside real clouds, the only forces involved are gravity, air pressure, and surface tension, and the water droplets don't interact with each other, then these are the only shapes they'll have.

The only other force that I know is involved is electric charge, and I'd expect that to be mostly inside the clouds and not for large raindrops on the way down. And I can't think of any interactions that would make a difference. So my guess is that those are the shapes. Though there could be something I haven't thought of.

I remember looking at thick shampoo in transparent bottles. I'd turn them over and air bubbles would travel to the top in raindrop shapes. That's because the air bubbles didn't have much surface tension at all. Water has so much surface tension that you won't see a raindrop tail.

The earlier video is different.

[image: higher]
[image: second]
[image: third]
[image: fourth]
[image: next higher]
[image: fifth]

It's like with the other one it did slow scans, and this time it does quick scans that sometimes record the same raindrop in two places.

Comment: That is just light filtering through leaves and branches . the ones onth reight are reflections from the windows of the building.

Comment: They last for one frame. The white dots in the trees stay there pretty much the whole time without moving. I think you're mistaken about this. Your 223k points says you don't make a lot of physics mistakes.

Comment: You are correct that they only appear on this one  printscreen ,  but not the interpretation. I think it must be drops  sliding down the camera front taking the video.

Comment: Upvoted for circling the raindrops in the video still. However, the “big blob” suggestion is incorrect. To get an idea why, take a stroll across a tall bridge near you, empty your water bottle off the side, and watch how the water breaks up into droplets. To answer the question “what about more water,” plan a hike to a waterfall, and watch how that stream breaks up.

Comment: @rob, I tend to agree with you about the blobs. Still, with lots of rain falling from a great height, strange things can happen. It isn't the way to bet, but I wouldn't rule it out.

Comment: have deleted my answer , because after looking again with print screen I think the white dots are light coming through the leaves and branches, It needs more sophisticated tools to manipulate the video, or if the streaks you point out are drops, it needs a faster camera to see the drops..

Comment: look at this https://www.videvo.net/video/close-up-shot-rain-drops-falling-on-leaves/783004/ . the camera is not fast enough, except for the bouncing drops on the leaves which are slower

Comment: @annav Agreed! It takes a faster camera to see raindrops as spheres, a slow one will see them as lines. My eye sees them as long lines probably because they have a certain continuity.

Comment: It's the same effect that makes the wheel on this famous old photo of a [racecar](https://phototechsf.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/race-car-by-jacques-henri-lartigue/) elliptical rather than circular.  The car has moved forward between when the bottom of the wheel was exposed and the top.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That's a fascinating picture! I think to get that effect, he aimed the camera at the moving car. That's why the driver is not blurred. He had a shutter that revealed a little bit of the image at a time, starting at the bottom. (That's why the spectator's legs aren't blurred out.) The shutter traveled up the picture about twice as fast as the camera panned. Today, old cameras have the rolling shutter while newer ones grab the whole frame at once. Then a raindrop might provide enough light to set off all the cells it passes during the frame, or maybe too little for any of them.

Comment: @JThomas I updated the question. Please review